# Do singularities in black holes violate the Bekenstein bound?

Tags: black-holes, entropy, event-horizon, singularities, information

Since all matter falling past the event horizon must hit the singularity in a finite time, I'm assuming that this means that all matter will eventually settle down into the singularity. If this is so, then the singularity must contain all the information about all the particles that ever fell through the horizon. But since a singularity is defined to be an entity of zero volume, does this mean that singularities violate the [Bekenstein bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound) by containing more information than they are allowed to? Or am I missing some thing(s) here?